# Searching in 3 tables in one database in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a method that searches in the database based on the List of object i created in the drop-down list,but in 3 tables and returns as below, but since its 3 tables i'm confused as to how to return at the end.
I'm new to MVC.
Please help!!

```
 public ActionResult Search(string searchBy, string list)
    {

        var ola = new object[] { "Exchange", "Business Sector", "Country", "Company Name" };
        ViewBag.list = new SelectList(ola);


        var exchange = from a in db.Exchange_tbl
                       select a;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy))
        {
            if (list.Equals("Exchange"))
            {
                exchange = exchange.Where(a => a.exchangeName.Contains(searchBy));
            }
        }


        var businessSector = from s in db.BusinessSector_tbl
                             select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy))
        {
            if (list.Equals("Business Sector"))
            {
                businessSector = businessSector.Where(s => s.businessSectorDesc.Contains(searchBy));
            }
        }

       var country = from x in db.Country_tbl
                      select x;
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy))
        { 
                if (list.Equals("Country"))
                {
                    var countries = db.Country_tbl.ToList();
                    List<int> countryIds = countries.Where(x => x.countryName.ToLower().Contains(searchBy.ToLower())).Select(x => x.countryID).ToList();
                    List<int> companyIds = db.countrycompviews.Where(x => countryIds.Contains(x.countryID)).Select(x => x.companyID).ToList();
                    country = country.Where(s => companyIds.Contains(s.countryID));
                }
        }


        return View(exchange.Union(country).ToList());
    }
```

Comment: did you tried to use ViewBag ???

Comment: 1] you could send the results in a `ViewBag.SearchResults`. And in your view, you could have a switch case and cast them and display them accordingly. or 2] you can create a container mode with a List of Exchange, List of BusinessSector etc  as properties and display them in your view according to  your selected item. I think second one would be good as you could display multiple lists if your requirement changes

Answer (score 0):

Create a container model like this.

```
public class SearchResult 
{
    public string SelectedList { get; set; }

    public IList<Exchange> Exchanges { get; set; }

    public IList<BusinessSector> BusinessSectors { get; set; }

    public IList<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller, after you have queried all the tables, populate all the lists:

```
SearchResult searchResult = new SearchResult {
    BusinessSectors = businessSector,
    Countries = country,
    Exchanges = exchange,
    SelectedList = list
}

// logic to get the selectlist for the dropdown

return View(searchResult);
```

in your view, add the `@model Models.SearchResult` on top of your view.

```
@switch (model.SelectedList)
{
    case "Exchange": 
    // logic to loop through display model.Exchanges in a table or something

    case "Business Sector":
    // logic to loop through display model.BusinessSectors 

    case "Country":
    // logic to loop through display model.Countries
}
```